# What does '%' sign do in this particular case?

Tags: python

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

''' see the line bellow '''
%matplotlib inline # <- here
```

I understand what '%' is for in math and in strings, but what does it do here? Is it also a string? Can't tell. Can some one elaborate.

**Edit**: 
Folks in the comments helped me to narrow it down to ipython/Jupyter.

[python 2](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/interactive/tutorial.html)

[python 3](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/tutorial.html)

And if you are using ipython, try `%magic` to get more info on magic ipython/Jupyter functions.

Comment: It terminates the script with SyntaxError.

Comment: Technically, it's not Python. It marks a special builtin command provided by the iPython interpreter.

Comment: @chepner if you think it's correct maybe you can put it as an answer and I'll mark it since you are first.

Comment: You could just search that... http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/1.x/examples/notebooks/Part%203%20-%20Plotting%20with%20Matplotlib.ipynb